# Elegant way to pre-select option in select-form based on routing parameter?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a component with a single `<select>` form. Below the form is an empty table with a specific layout, implemented in a child component.

The list of available items is currently fetched from a REST API once during component initialization (`getFamilies`). It is important for the child component that the `selectedFamily` is an object and not just a string.

Upon selection I use `router.navigate` to update the route to give the user the possibility to bookmark/share the page.

Currently I use the `router.params` "callback" to manually record the family name in a separate variable `selectedFamilyName` and use it to lookup the family object when loading the list from the service:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

import { Family }  from './family';
import { FamilyService } from './family.service';
import { FamilyTable }   from './family-table.component';

@Component({
  template: `
      <div class="form-group">
        <select [(ngModel)]="selectedFamily" (ngModelChange)="onSelect($event)"
            class="form-control">
          <option *ngFor="let family of families" [ngValue]="family">
            {{ family.name }}
          </option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <familytable [family]=selectedFamily></familytable>
  `,
  directives: [FamilyTable],
})

export class FamilyList implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  errorMessage: string;
  families: Family[] = [];
  selectedFamily: Family;
  selectedFamilyString: string = "";

  private _sub: any;

  constructor(
      private _route: ActivatedRoute,
      private _router: Router,
      private _familyService: FamilyService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getFamilies();

    this._sub = this._route.params.subscribe(params => {
      // record the family string for list item selection
      this.selectedFamilyString = params['family'];
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this._sub.unsubscribe();
  }

  getFamilies() {
    this._familyService.getFamilies().subscribe(
      families => {
        this.families = families;
        this.selectedFamily = this.families.find(family => family.name === this.selectedFamilyString);
      },
      error => this.errorMessage = <any>error,
    );
  }

  onSelect(family: Family) {
    this._router.navigate(['families', family.name]);
  }
}
```

This manual book-keeping feels cumbersome. Is there are better, more elegant or even recommended way to do this sort of thing?

Comment: If family is an object then I'm afraid, no. If it is just a string you can simplify.

Comment: Would it help if I'd move the logic to the service instead? This way I could also implement a refresh of the family list inside the service and push out update events to this component.

Comment: You can move the code somewhere else if that helps, but I think the work it does has still to be done and I don't see a way to make it shorter (not much spare time and creative energy today so this doesn't mean too much)